# How to restructure event data to dyadic in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
ID  Year 
1   1990
2   1990
3   1991
4   1992
5   1995
```

I want to add six countries to each observation (let's say countries A, B, C, D, E, F). In total, I will have 30 observations. So I expect the data to be like this:

```
    ID  Year    Country
    1    1990     A
    1    1990     B
    1    1990     C
    1    1990     D
    1    1990     E
    1    1990     F
    2    1990     A
    2    1990     B
    2    1990     C
    2    1990     D
    2    1990     E
    2    1990     F
    3    1991     A
    3    1991     B
    3    1991     C
    3    1991     D
    3    1991     E
    3    1991     F
    4    1992     A
    4    1992     B
    4    1992     C
    4    1992     D
    4    1992     E
    4    1992     F
    5    1995     A
    5    1995     B
    5    1995     C
    5    1995     D
    5    1995     E
    5    1995     F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, Country = LETTERS[1:6])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 30 × 3
      ID  Year Country
   <int> <int> <chr>  
 1     1  1990 A      
 2     1  1990 B      
 3     1  1990 C      
 4     1  1990 D      
 5     1  1990 E      
 6     1  1990 F      
 7     2  1990 A      
 8     2  1990 B      
 9     2  1990 C      
10     2  1990 D      
# … with 20 more rows
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rep`

```
out <- cbind(df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), each = 6),], Country = LETTERS[1:6])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1995L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one more question. I have real country names. What do I need to use instead of  `LETTERS[1:6]?`

Comment: @Santiago99 you pass a vector i.e. `c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")`

Comment: @Santiago99 if it works, please consider to accept solution by clicking on the tick mark. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
countries <- LETTERS[1:6] # whatever you really have as a vector
out <- merge(dat, data.frame(Country = countries), by = NULL)
out[c(1:3, 28:30),]
#    ID Year Country
# 1   1 1990       A
# 2   2 1990       A
# 3   3 1991       A
# 28  3 1991       F
# 29  4 1992       F
# 30  5 1995       F
```

Note that this works with `data.frame` and `tbl_df`, but `data.table::merge` does not allow `by=NULL` for cartesian expansion.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Year = c(1990L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1995L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```